# how do i put my print variable in an outhandle so that it prints into a txt file

Tags: python, regex, variables, output, nested-loops

this is my code, I am trying to learn about regexes and nested loops by outputting a summarization of my regex into a txt file.  In the summary I am trying to make a variable for the last three just like "student_*name" and "student*_seq" instead of the str(51) <- needs to find the start position of the longest chain (regex #3), str(63) <- needs to be (regex #1) and str(m.group) <- same issue as (regex #3) trying to make the print value into a variable so i can put it into the summary (regex #2)

```
{python polyq,eval=T,echo=T}
student_name = "Doe" 
student_seq = " "
seqs = open("sequences/all_seq.tsv","r")
for l in seqs:
  fields=l.split(" ")
  a = fields[0]
  b = fields[1]
  if a == student_name:
    student_seq = b

import re
pattern = re.compile("(CAA|CAG)")
for m in re.finditer(pattern, student_seq):
      print(m.start(),m.end(),m.group(0))
      
pattern = re.compile("(CAA|CAG)+")
for m in re.finditer(pattern, student_seq):
      print(m.start(0))    #<-regex3  
      print(len(m.group(0)))   #<-regex1
      print(m.group(0))     #<-regex2

      
out_handle = open("polyq.txt","w")
out_handle.write("My name is " +
            student_name +
            " and my sequence is " +
            student_seq +
            "The longest polyglutamine tract start position is " +
            str(51) + 
            ". The DNA length of longest polyglutamine tract is " +
            str(63) +
            ". The sequence for longest polyglutamine tract is " +
            str(m.group(0)) + "\n")
out_handle.close()
```

Ive tried making it a str value, I tried establishing it as a value (longest = print(m.group(0))) still not the answer and whatever is included in the summary right now gives me an output of NONE, This is the output into my txt file

```
My name is Doe and my sequence is ATGGCGACCCTGGAAAAGCTGATGAAGGCCTTCGAGTCCCTCAAGTCCTTCCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAACAGCCGCCA
The longest polyglutamine tract start position is 51. The DNA length of longest polyglutamine tract is 63. The sequence for longest polyglutamine tract is None
```

Comment: You are not writing the regex matches into  the file, you are just `print`ing them.

Comment: how would i do that? by establishing them as variables?

Comment: Yes, collect them into list(s).